# Show that $ x\mapsto e^x$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show that $x\mapsto e^x$ is continuous ? We suppose that we don't now anything about this function except that that for all $x\in\mathbb R$ that $$e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$$

So I have that $$e^{x+h}-e^x=e^x(e^h-1)$$
but I have to show that $$\lim_{h\to 0}(e^h-1)=0.$$

How can I do it ?

Comment: You can't. The functional equation $e^{x+y} = e^x\cdot e^y$ alone does not imply continuity.

Comment: Sure you need more than $e^{x+y}=e^x e^y$.

Comment: Ok, so can we have a condition less strong that the continuity at $x=0$ to have the continuity ?

Comment: There are known sufficient conditions for this.  Such as "Lebesgue measurable" or "bounded on some interval".

Comment: Nice reading on the topic [Chapter VII, A Brief History of the
Exponential Function, page 498](https://www.fa.uni-tuebingen.de/research/publications/1999/one-parameter-semigroups-for-linear-evolution-equations/engel-nagel_one-parameter-semigroups.pdf)

Comment: Could you give me a exemple of function such that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and which is not continuous ?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot prove it if your only assumption is that
$$
e^{x+y} = e^x e^y.
$$

In fact with the axiom of choice it is possible to construct an additive function which is not linear. With this additive but not linear function you are able to construct a function satisfying the property above which is not continuous in any point.

One of the following is enough to prove the continuity:

1. $e^x$ is continuous in at least one point
2. $e^x$ is monotone
3. there is a non-empty interval where $e^x$ is bounded
4. $e^x$ is measurable

Comment: Or 3. $e^x$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $0$

Comment: right... I add it!

Comment: or 4. $e^x$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}$. ([Banach-Sierpinski theorem](https://books.google.se/books?id=U3k8yfchaPYC&lpg=PA501&dq=banach%20sierpinski&hl=sv&pg=PA501#v=onepage&q=banach%20sierpinski&f=false)).

Comment: how the fact that $x\mapsto e^x$ is increasing imply that it's continuous ? I tried to prove it, but I can't conclude.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation#Properties_of_other_solutions

Answer (score 2):

Since there exist discontinuous functions $f$ satisfying $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ you'll need a bit more than just that. Since $$e^{x+y} - e^x = e^x(e^y - 1)$$ it would suffice to know that $g(x) = e^x$ is continuous at the single point $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, continuity is a consequence of convexity, but the strategy for proving that $f(x)=e^x$ is a convex function depends on the way such function is defined. Ultimately, it boils down to proving that:
$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=1,$$
giving $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^x=\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$ as a consequence.